# Populating UITableView dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have the following code to fetch the data from URL, store it in arrays, and display it inside the table.

Now the issue is my URL which is feeding data to the tables changes according to the button click i.e. If user clicks button [gainer], data gets fetched from URL related to gainer and so on.

As I have called gainer method in didLoad method, initially data is displayed from the respective URL.But on button click no action is taken. The reason is I'm populating the arrays in methods (gainer and looser) but table is fetching data from the arrays at the time of table creation(and arrays are empty at that point).

I have created button in design view while I'm creating table programmatically.

**fetchdataViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface fetchdataViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    NSMutableArray *arr1;
    NSMutableArray *atarr;
    NSMutableArray *arr2;
    NSMutableArray *a;
    NSMutableArray *b;
    NSMutableArray *c;
    NSMutableArray *d;
    UITableView *aTableView;
}
-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)btnClicked1:(id)sender;
-(void)gainer;
-(void)looser;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *arr1;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *arr2;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *atarr;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *a;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *b;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *c;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *d;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIWebView *webView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITableView *aTableView;
@end
```

**fetchdataViewController.m**

```
#import "fetchdataViewController.h"

@implementation fetchdataViewController

NSMutableArray *atarr;
NSMutableArray *arr1;
NSMutableArray *arr2;
NSMutableArray *a;
NSMutableArray *b;
NSMutableArray *c;
NSMutableArray *d;
NSMutableString *mainstr;
NSMutableString *str;
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize arr1;
@synthesize arr2;
@synthesize atarr;
@synthesize a;
@synthesize b;
@synthesize c;
@synthesize d;
@synthesize aTableView;

int i,j;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [a count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell"; 

    static NSInteger StateTag = 1;
    static NSInteger CapitalTag = 2;
    static NSInteger StateTag1 = 3;
    static NSInteger StateTag2 = 4;


    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = 10; 
        frame.origin.y = 5;
        frame.size.height = 35;
        frame.size.width = 170;


        UILabel *capitalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        capitalLabel.tag = CapitalTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:capitalLabel];     

        frame.origin.x += 125;
        UILabel *stateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        stateLabel.tag = StateTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:stateLabel];

        frame.origin.x += 100;
        UILabel *stateLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        stateLabel1.tag = StateTag1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:stateLabel1];


        frame.origin.x += 100;
        UILabel *stateLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        stateLabel2.tag = StateTag2;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:stateLabel2];


    }
    UILabel *capitalLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:CapitalTag];
    UILabel *stateLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:StateTag];
    UILabel *stateLabel1 = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:StateTag1];
    UILabel *stateLabel2 = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:StateTag2];

    capitalLabel.text=[a objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    stateLabel.text = [b objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    stateLabel1.text = [c objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    stateLabel2.text = [d objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}


-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender{
    [self gainer];
}

-(IBAction)btnClicked1:(id)sender {

    [self looser];
}

-(void)gainer{
    arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arr2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    a=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    b=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    c=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    d=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ipad.idealake.com/default.aspx?id=G"];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:req];

    //storing page data in string
    mainstr=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    atarr=[mainstr componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];

    NSString *str2;
    NSString *str3;
    for(int i=0; i<[atarr count]-1; i++)
    {
        // NSLog(@"i=:%i",i); 

        NSMutableString *str = [atarr objectAtIndex:i];
        if (str!= nil)            
            arr1=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
            for (int k=0;k<[arr1 count];k++)
            {                
                str2 = [arr1 objectAtIndex:k];                
                [arr2 addObject:str2];
                            }


        }
        else
        {
            //NSLog (@"Nill");
        }

    }
    for(int l=0;l<[arr2 count]/4;l++){
        str3=[arr2 objectAtIndex:4*l];
        [a addObject:str3];

        str3=[arr2 objectAtIndex:(4*l)+1];
        [b addObject:str3];

        str3=[arr2 objectAtIndex:(4*l)+2];
        [c addObject:str3];

        str3=[arr2 objectAtIndex:(4*l)+3];
        [d addObject:str3];
    }    
}

-(void)looser{

    arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arr2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    a=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    b=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    c=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    d=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ipad.idealake.com/default.aspx?id=L"];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:req];

    mainstr=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    atarr=[mainstr componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];

    NSString *str2;
    NSString *str3;
    for(int i=0; i<[atarr count]-1; i++)
    {

        NSMutableString *str = [atarr objectAtIndex:i];
        if (str!= nil)
        {

            arr1=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
            for (int k=0;k<[arr1 count];k++)
            {

                str2 = [arr1 objectAtIndex:k];
                [arr2 addObject:str2];
            }          

        }
        else
        {
            //NSLog (@"Nill");
        }

    }
    for(int l=0;l<[arr2 count]/4;l++){
        str3=[arr2 objectAtIndex:4*l];
        [a addObject:str3];

        str3=[arr2 objectAtIndex:(4*l)+1];
        [b addObject:str3];

        str3=[arr2 objectAtIndex:(4*l)+2];
        [c addObject:str3];

        str3=[arr2 objectAtIndex:(4*l)+3];
        [d addObject:str3];
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arr2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    a=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    b=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    c=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    d=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self gainer];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    aTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    aTableView.dataSource = self;
    aTableView.delegate = self;
    aTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 720, 500);
    [self.view addSubview:aTableView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

***UPDATE***

When I run the below code, I get this output. That shaded grey portion is my main concern.

[image: Screenshot] 
***THANKS IN ADVANCE***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell your `UITableView` that the data has changed by calling `reloadData`.

Comment: @GAMA It was a speed typing contest anyway :)

Comment: Lolz... But there is 1 more issue. Table is not displayed in a perfect manner within a frame.

Comment: @GAMA You may want to make a separate question out of it, and perhaps attach a screenshot or two to better explain what you mean by "non-perfect manner".

Comment: It's not worthy a new question I guess. So I have uploaded the screenshot and if you can help in this problem, it will be helpful.

Comment: @GAMA I do not see a link to the screenshot of your running application showing the wrong layout. Did you forget to add a link to the picture?

Comment: When I run the below code, I get this output. That shaded grey portion is my main concern.

http://i.imgur.com/qLAtc.png

Comment: @GAMA Your link does not open. Doesn't Stack Overflow let you attach pictures to questions?

Comment: it does. And I have attached it at the end of question. Try clicking 
  http://i.imgur.com/qLAtc.png

Comment: @GAMA Oops, I think something was wrong with my inet connection last night, I couldn't see the image that you attached. I can see it now, and I suspect that something is wrong with the offset calculations inside the `if(cell == nil)` block of code. I do think that it is worth a separate question, though.

Comment: ok, I have posted it as separate que and found the ans ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471794/displaying-uitableview-in-proper-format

Answer (score 2):

Use [self.tableview reloadData] after each change of url and with new arrays filled.

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot and if you can help in this problem, it will be helpful.